# Escaping select option values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, escaping, html-select

I have a bunch of select boxes used to filter a large complex table whose contents is loaded via a sequence of ajax queries. As the table loads, not just the table but the select box filter update to reflect the current available options. As the use may already have selected options to filter the table at this point, I have a bit of code to preserve the currently selected value:

```
    if($('#CourseFilter').length) {
        selected = $('#CourseFilter').val();
        $('#CourseFilter').replaceWith(sel);
        if(selected != '') $('#CourseFilter option[value="'+escape(selected)+'"]').prop('selected', true);
    } else {
        sel.appendTo('#filters'); // Adding fitler for first time.
    }
```

This works for most of the filters, but a couple, such as `#CourseFilter`, reset back to default instead of remembering current selection. It think it is because the values in these lists contain special characters such as `-`, `/` and `\`. I have tried using `escape` but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you are probably looking for:**

You should be able to just set the value of `sel`, instead of finding the right `<option>` and manually selecting that:

```
sel.val(selected);
```

---

**If you want to find the right `<option>`:**

You can avoid the escaping issue altogether by filtering for the right `<option>` using **[jQuery.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**:

```
$('#CourseFilter option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).val() === selected;
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: I was avoiding sel.val(selected) on the basis that it could potentially create an option from an invalid value. On the other hand I probably won't be passing it an invalid value, so it should be safe...

Comment: `.val(...)` won't create a new `<option>`, so it should be safe to use.

Comment: Ah okay. I read in the comments of some other SO answer that it does. Maybe that behaviour has been fixed or the comment was mistaken. Thanks for the clarification...

Comment: You can easily prove or disprove this yourself. Create an empty `<select>`, call `.val("foo")` on it, and see if a new `<option>` has been added.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out I was on the wrong track anyway. The unwanted behaviour was actually caused by a conflicting piece of older code!

Answer (score 1):

No need to look for each `<option>` since `val()` is both a getter and a setter.

Just use `val()` to set value on new `<select>`

```
if($('#CourseFilter').length) {
    selected = $('#CourseFilter').val();
    $('#CourseFilter').replaceWith(sel);
    sel.val(selected);
} else {
    sel.appendTo('#filters'); // Adding fitler for first time.
}
```